# Flutter - SharedPreferences call undefined method getAll

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I'm playing around with flutter and SharedPreferences package.
I have set up a simple project to understand how to use this package but as soon as I lunch the project I get:

> No implementation found for method getAll on channel
> plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences

Can't figured out what's wrong.

here is my repository:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

abstract class AuthenticationRepository {
  Future<User> getCurrentUser();
  Future<User> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class RestAuthenticationProvider extends AuthenticationRepository {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  var httpClient = new Dio();

  @override
  Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
    String token = await this.getToken();
    if (null == token) {
      return null;
    }

    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;

    return User(
      name: prefs.getString('user_name') ?? '',
      email: prefs.getString('user_email') ?? '',
    );
  }

  Future<String> getToken() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    String token = prefs.getString('user_token') ?? null;
    return token;
  }

  @override
  Future<User> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    Response response = await httpClient.post(
      kIssueTokenUrl,
      data: {
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "device_name": 'Mobile app',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw AuthenticationException(
        message: 'Nome utente o password sbagliati.',
      );
    }

    String token = response.data.toString();

    httpClient.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    httpClient.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
    Response userInfoResponse = await httpClient.get(kGetUserInfoUrl);

    if (userInfoResponse.statusCode != 200) {
      throw AuthenticationException(
        message: 'Nome utente o password sbagliati.',
      );
    }

    String userName = userInfoResponse.data['name'];
    String userEmail = userInfoResponse.data['email'];

    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.setString('user_token', token);
    prefs.setString('user_name', userName);
    prefs.setString('user_email', userEmail);

    return User(
      name: userName,
      email: userEmail,
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.remove('token');
    prefs.remove('user_name');
    prefs.remove('user_email');
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is the User model, just for references:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class User {
  final String name;
  final String email;

  User({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.email,
  });

  @override
  String toString() => 'User { name: $name, email: $email}';
}
```

I just use `getString`, `setString` and `remove`, can't figured out why getAll should be called and fails.

EDIT:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           19,3s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/christiangiupponi/Dev/FlutterApp/test/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'shared_preferences' not found
@import shared_preferences;
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are on the latest version (0.5.12+2) and run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`. If you're on iOS, run `pod install` too. You can also try deleting the app from the phone.

If the error persists, add `SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});` to your `main()`.

Comment: I have followed your instruction but now I get a new error in console, I have edited my question because it is too long for the comment

Comment: Try opening Xcode project from Project.xcodeproj instead of Project.xcworkspace

Comment: I have deleted the `ios/Podfile` and runned again the build and it seems to compile now

Comment: Glad to hear it :)